# What is a good practice to write unit-test on .net core Ihostedservice?

Tags: unit-testing, microservices, background-process, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have a background task initiated in .net core 2.0 startup, inherits from  backgroundservice, implementing StartAsync, StopAsync and ExecuteAsync.  This task is to update some data in database table periodically based on some business logic.

While I can run the backgroundtask as an application and test using logs, db check and with the help of other tools, can the unit-testing is necessary for testing the backgroundtask? If so how to register the task as a service with dependencies and trigger the start and stop methods to assert the actual vs expected? Appreciate some basic sample unit-test method on testing timer based .net core ihostedservice backgroundtask.

Here is my basic test start just for sample, but not completed yet.  Having said that, this is just a thought but not the exact working test.  Here is what need some help from the community.  Can also add some more asserts i.e. Assert.Verify()?

```
  [Fact]
        public async void Run_background_task_success()
        {
            //Arrange
            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

            services.AddHostedService<BackgroundManagerTask>();

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var service = serviceProvider.GetService<IHostedService>() as BackgroundManagerTask;

            var isExecuted = false;
            if(await service.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None))
{
isExecuted = true;
}

            await Task.Delay(10000);
            Assert.True(isExecuted);

            await service.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I usually do it. You mention you are going to the database to update some data, so I'm assuming you are expecting that as a dependency from `BackgroundManager`

```
[Fact]
public void BackgroundManagerUpdatingDataTest()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IDataAccess> dbMock = new Mock<IDataAccess>();
    dbMock.Setup(x => x.UpdateSomethingInDB(It.IsAny<BusinessObject>())).Returns(1); // One row updated from the DML in UpdateSomethingInDB from the BusinessObject
    
    BackgroundManager sut = new BackgroundManager(dbMock.Object); // System under test.

    // Act
    await sut.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    await Task.Delay(500); // Give the test some time to execute.
    await sut.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None); // Stop the Background Service.

    // Assert
    dbMock.Verify(x => x.UpdateSomethingInDB(It.IsAny<BusinessObject>()), Times.Exactly(1));
}
```

Above, we are plainly testing the update to the database occurred by Mocking the data access call and verifying that it was called exactly once.

You could of course Mock any other dependency out using [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) and Assert on anything else you want to verify.